# Pardot Visit query API - generic query not available

Tags: python-3.x, pardot

I am trying to extract/sync data through Pardot API v4 into a local DB. Most APIs were fine, just used the query method with created_after search criteria. But the Visit API does not seem to support neither a generic query of *all* visit data, nor a created_after search criteria to retrieve new items.

As far as I can see I can only query Visits in the context of a Visitor or a Prospect.

Any ideas why, and how could I implement synchronisation? (sorry, no access to Pardot DB...)
I have been using pypardot4 python wrapper for convenience but would be happy to use the API natively if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get a response from Pardot support, and they have confirmed that such response filtering is not available on the Visits API. I asked for a feature request, but hardly any chance to get enough up-votes to be considered :(